# Best way to replace a 3in drain Tee

Tags: plumbing

There is a blockage in the drain pipe in my basement. I was able to open the 3in plug and can feel a blockage about 6in below the Tee in the cast iron pipe. The cast iron pipe must have an elbow  to an horizontal pipe (under the flooring, not visible) leading to the main exit port which is about 5ft away from this junction.
I am planning to take out the Tee so that the block is accessible to clean or may be replace the cast iron part.
I am quite handy but not much plumbing experience. Appreciate any ideas on how to go about. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Your description of the plumbing is clear, but your question is not. Please revise to be more specific about the problem. You mention a tee in the cast iron, but I'm not sure where that is. What are you trying to remove?

Comment: Also, what's above the top of this photo? You'll almost certainly need to cut out that assembly, so specific advice depends on context.

Comment: What kind of equipment have you tried?

Comment: The problem is water gets backed up because of the clog in the cast iron part, below the PVC Tee (ie the drain plug part). The backed up water then back flows into the basement sink carrying some junk that collects in the sink. I thought the blockage might be around the plug that I can easily clean up. It appears there is some solid blockage about 6in below the plug that is not accessible. I think I have cut off the part (assuming it's the T) that holds the drainage plug so that I get access to clean the blockage and replace with a new one. Not exactly sure how to, and the effort.

Comment: I tried a manual auger with a handle to rotate to catch things like hair. The auger doesnt go beyond 6in because of the block. I can feel a small opening (that is helping water to trickle and eventually clear up the backlog). I I push the auger into this hole I cant rotate as it hits something solid

Comment: Buy a 30 camera to take a look in there. Also, you might try something sharp like a corkscrew where you could grab it and pull it back up.

Comment: do you have kids that dropped some toy in it

Comment: That T should be a Y, also the top part is some contraption fitting different pipe size together, you might have to cut it above and remove the T so you might reach the solid object, then find the owner, then ??

Comment: Try a hook made of stiff wire